# How to start an app with WinAppDriver as an admin

Tags: c#, appium, desktop-application, runas, winappdriver

A Desktop application should be started with admin privileges.
How to start it for testing with WinAppDriver?

I am doing it with

```
AppiumOptions options = new AppiumOptions();
options.AddAdditionalCapability("app", UltreonAppId);
options.AddAdditionalCapability("deviceName", "WindowsPC");
options.AddAdditionalCapability("ms:experimental-webdriver", true);

WindowsDriver<WindowsElement> session = new(new Uri(WindowsApplicationDriverUrl), options);
```

The application is not starting properly because the application should update registries on a start-up, and that can be done only with admin permissions.